# Simple Css problem for Mouseover

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

Could someone help me in CSS. I have text "Featured Page". On hovering(on mouseover), 
i should see a picture on its right. Currently i get a picture under the text when i use the following Css. I need it bigger and right side of the text.

I have never worked on a css page.. So please don't take me wrong.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#Style { 
position:absolute; 
visibility:hidden; 
border:solid 1px #CCC; 
padding:5px;
</style>
```

My javascript is :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function ShowPicture(id,Source) { 
if (Source=="1"){ 
var pos = $('' + id+'').offset();   
var width = $('' + id+'').width();
var popupHeight = $(''+id+'').height(); 

if (document.layers) document.layers(''+id+'').visibility = "show" 
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible" 
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility =       "visible" 
 $(''+id+'').css( { "left": (pos.left - width - 272) + "px", "top": (pos.top - popupHeight + 5) + "px" } );
} 
else 
if (Source=="0"){ 
if (document.layers) document.layers(''+id+'').visibility = "hide" 
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "hidden" 
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "hidden" 
} 
}
```

My html is

```
 <td valign="middle" class="table_td td top" style="width: 347px">  <span     class="feature_text" style="cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="ShowPicture('Style',1)" onmouseout="ShowPicture('Style',0)" id="a1"> Featured Merchant Ad  </span><br /> </td>

<div id="Style"><img src=""></div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your css is broken. And why did you call that element "Style"?

Comment: 1. This shouldn't work at all, because there's no `}` 2. Post HTML or we can only guess.

Comment: I have added my html and javascript. Please have a look at it @naugtur

Comment: Both answers given here already show good ways to do that. Your code is not how it should be done, sorry. Get rid of this JavaScript part and adopt one of the solutions. There's no need for Javascript here.

Answer (score 2):

You could style the elements hover event to show a `background` image. You'll probably need to mess with the `margins` to get it to show up just right

```
.item 
{ 
    border:solid 1px #CCC; 
    padding:5px;
}

.item:hover
{
    background: url(../images/background.png) middle right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#mytext {
 position: relative;
}

#mytext img {
 position: relative;
 visibiliy: hidden;
}

#mytext:hover img {
 visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

And this HTML:

```
<p id="mytext">
 Some text...
 <img src="..." />
</p>
```